# SSH client not trying my keys in ssh-agent

Tags: ssh, ssh-agent

I'm on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5, and my SSH client is behaving in a way I can't explain or resolve.

My goal is simply to connect to a server with:

`ssh -A core@12.34.56.78`

When I add `-v` to this, I can see that my SSH client fails to try any key other than my `~/.ssh/id_rsa` key.  I've confirmed that ssh-agent is running, and used `ssh-add -l` to confirm the key I want is added.

Here's what I'm running in my local bash prompt:

```
# Run ssh-agent
bash-3.2$ eval $(ssh-agent)
Agent pid 7786

# Confirm it's running
bash-3.2$ sudo ps aux | grep ssh-agent
josh             7794   0.0  0.0  2432772    676 s000  S+    1:32PM   0:00.00 grep ssh-agent
josh             7786   0.0  0.0  2480640   2180   ??  Us    1:31PM   0:00.04 ssh-agent

# Login successfully by explicitly specifying a key
bash-3.2$ ssh -i sandbox core@12.34.56.78
Last login: Tue Aug 18 20:13:31 2015 from X.Y.189.46
CoreOS stable (723.3.0)
core@ip-10-200-4-138 ~ $ exit
logout
Connection to 12.34.56.78 closed.

# Now attempt to connect using ssh-agent
bash-3.2$ ssh-add sandbox
Identity added: sandbox (sandbox)
bash-3.2$ ssh -A core@12.34.56.78

# My just-added key isn't tried, so I'm prompted for a password
core@12.34.56.78's password:
```

Any help would be much appreciated!

**Update:** 
As requested, here's the verbose output:

```
bash-3.2$ ssh -v -A core@12.34.56.78
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/josh/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/josh/.ssh/config line 1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 102: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to 12.34.56.78 [12.34.56.78] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /Users/josh/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/josh/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/josh/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/josh/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.7
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.7 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REQUEST(1024<2048<8192) sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_GROUP
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_INIT sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_DH_GEX_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: RSA a8:d9:fb:07:a6:71:de:99:76:9e:55:9c:bd:68:87:55
debug1: Host '12.34.56.78' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /Users/josh/.ssh/known_hosts:164
debug1: ssh_rsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Offering RSA public key: /Users/josh/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Trying private key: /Users/josh/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: password
```

Comment: `ssh-add -L` should confirm if you have running agent and you have valid connection to it.

Comment: `ssh-add -L` outputs my public key file, so that seems to be working.

Comment: Verbose output of SSH command would help also

Comment: Have you tried running it with `dstruss`?

Comment: @Josh Padnick Did you ever figure out what was causing this in your case? (I'm seeing the same thing on a freshly installed Ubuntu 18.04 box of mine)

Answer (score 2):

As you mentioned, the `ssh` command wants a key named `id_rsa`.

When you do:

```
$ ssh-add sandbox
```

you add a key named `sandbox` to your agent.

So there is a discrepancy.

The solution on the SSH command line is to use the identify file option:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/other_keys/sandbox ...
```

> **Note:** *I use a subfolder for other keys, because there is a harsh limit, which makes sense, but it will bite you if you access many servers, each with their own key; see https://askubuntu.com/questions/419546/ssh-never-ask-for-a-password for additional details.*

In order to avoid having to use the `-i` option all the time, you can instead add that information in your `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host example.com
  Hostname example.com
  User YourUserName
  PasswordAuthentication no
  HostbasedAuthentication no
  IdentitiesOnly yes
  IdentityFile /home/<your-user-name>/.ssh/other_keys/sandbox
```

Now `ssh` will find that `IdentifyFile` option on its own. The search is based on the `Host`. You can actually use any name on that line, for example:

```
Host remote-sandbox
  ...
```

gives you the ability to use

```
$ ssh remote-sandbox
```

on your command line, without having to define `remote-sandbox` in your `/etc/hosts`.

You should not have to use the `ssh-add` command at all. The first time you run the `ssh` command, it will ask you for your password and if you have the agent available, it will automatically save it there. Using the `ssh-add` can be useful if the `ssh` command is going to run without you at your computer (or, in case you use a system such as Docker, to preload the key because `docker build ...` kills the input shell).

Answer (score 1):

The verbose output shows that your keys *are* being offered. just not accepted.  The most common problem here is permissions.

On the remote server, run:

```
ls -ld $HOME $HOME/.ssh $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

You will see output like this:

```
wwalker@serenity:~$ ls -ld $HOME $HOME/.ssh $HOME/.ssh/authorized_keys
drwx------. 66 wwalker wwalker 36864 2016-08-28 12:31:03.241 /home/wwalker
drwx------.  2 wwalker wwalker 32768 2016-08-28 11:57:52.282 /home/wwalker/.ssh
-rw-------.  1 wwalker wwalker  3182 2015-09-27 12:07:58.000 /home/wwalker/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Fix whichever things have group or other write permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Is `sandbox` a version 1 or version 2 key?  If it's an old key, it might only be working with version 1 of the ssh protocol.  You can figure this out by running `ssh -A -1 core@52.26.187.69`.

Comment: Thx for the input.  It does appear to be an old key (running the code returned `Protocol major versions differ: 1 vs. 2`), however one of my colleagues, also running OS X (10.10 in his case vs. 10.10.5 in my case) can successfully log in with ssh-agent and the exact same key.

Comment: Probably your colleague is defaulting to ssh version 1.  This isn't necessarily advisable, but you can put `Protocol 1,2` in the appropriate stanza of your `~/.ssh/config` file (Below a line for `Host 12.34.56.78`.)  Better would be to insert a version 2 key in the `authorized_keys` file on the server machine.